# How do I separate user's messages and prevent them from stacking side by side?

Tags: html, css

1. I need to position the boxes left (for one user) and right (for another user).
2. I want the boxes to stack vertically. Now the boxes would line up side by side horizontally when I expand the window.

My bad example
[**JS bin bad example**](http://jsbin.com/kebawav/edit?html,css,output) 
screenshot below 
[image]

**html layout**

```
<div class="chatwindow">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="chat-other">
        <div class="chat-text"> chat content </div>
        <span class="chat-time"> 4.09 pm </span>
        <b>Other user</b>
    </div> 

    <div class="chat-mine"> <!-- content -->  </div> 
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chatwindow {
   overflow-y:auto;
}

.chat-mine { 
   float: right;
   clear: left;
   max-width: 236px;
   display: inline-block; 
   text-align: left;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 7px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
   margin-bottom: 9px;
   margin: 6px;
   padding:3px;
   background-color: #66ffff;
}

.chat-other {
   clear: right; 
   max-width: 236px;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 7px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
   margin-bottom: 9px;
   margin: 6px;
   padding:3px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}

.chat-text {
  padding: 5px 7px;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  &::after {
    content: " \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
    display: inline;
  }
}

.chat-time {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 7px;
}
```

I hope to have messages by me on one side, messages by other user on the other. 
The ideal example: 
[**JS bin good example**](http://jsbin.com/silibek/1/edit?html,css,output) 
screenshot also shown below:

[image]

Not sure why but I cant do position: relative on both my div and other use div to have them aligned on both sides

Comment: Ok done, added shorter code + picture of both good and bad examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `float:right;` on your answers (`.chat-mine`), and `clear:right;` on the other user's answers (`.chat-other`).

Comment: Thanks @Marc Brillault, somehow it doesnt work. My boxes still line up horizontally. But when I removed `display: inline-block;` it works ...but im not sure thats a permanent solution..

Comment: This does not fix the problem.